# What are WordPress installation percentages by version?

Tags: plugins, wordpress-version

I'm in the process of developing a plugin, and I'd like to figure out which versions of WordPress to support. But to get a good idea I'd need to know what percentages of old Wordpress versions make up the install base. Does such information exist?

Alternatively if such information doesn't exist, does anyone have a suggested version I should support my plugin back to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a page in the Codex that shows exactly that:

- [WordPress > About » Statistics](http://wordpress.org/about/stats/)

But really, it all depends on what features you're using.  A safe bet for a new plugin would be to support WordPress 3.1.X and above (since that's the current stable release).  You're setting yourself up for a lot of hurt if you try to do too much backwards compatibility work.

Comment: Up-voting you, because you beat me to the punch! :)

Answer (score 0):

[WordPress.org publishes the aggregate installation stats](http://wordpress.org/about/stats/) collected by api.wordpress.org.